# Using a name as a contraction with "is", syntax looks possessive?

Tags: american-english, names, contractions

"Bob is fat."

Would it be proper to do "Bob's fat."?

To me, this looks possessive, as if we're talking about his fat rather than using "fat" as an adjective. What's the proper way to do this?

"Bob is fat."

Comment: How High's a Chinaman (?)

Comment: Context is king. If the next word after *is* is an adjective or noun, the contraction will appear possessive. If it's a verb, adverb, or article, it will appear as a contraction.

Comment: For me, context provides enough clues to keep me from misreading the phrase. "Bob's fat but lovable" = contraction. "Bob's fat is not his greatest problem" = possessive. No problems there. Of course you could find syntactically ambiguous examples, but otherwise you're going to be fine—so yes, "Bob's fat" is proper (if not terribly _polite_).

Comment: The normally contracted sentence _Bob's fat_, meaning _Bob is fat_, **is** indistinguishable in speech from the noun phrase _Bob's fat_, meaning _the fat that Bob has_. So, yes, it does sound like the possessive, but this never causes confusion in speech, so why should it in writing? After all, how often do you talk about a person's fat as if it were separate from the rest of their body? And how often do you do **that** as a bare noun phrase, without a verb or adverb?

Comment: Even "Bob's fat but lovable [widget]" changes the dynamic (adjective = possessive).

Comment: "Hey, what's that around Bob's belly?" "Bob's fat."

Comment: It's perfectly legit, if occasionally confusing.  One needs to consider the context and whether the use of a contraction in such a situation could lead to misunderstanding.  (And besides, it's yet another way that one can have fun with the English language, and that's more important than Bob's adipose tissue anyway.)

Comment: @JohnLawler “After all, how often do you talk about a person's fat as if it were separate from the rest of their body?” — You clearly haven’t been spending enough quality conversation time with the lovable Mr. Lecter!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is that it's grammatically proper to write or say "Bob's fat," yes.

It indeed looks (and sounds) the same whether the intention is "Bob is fat" or "The fat of Bob." The difference in understanding would need to come from the context, in writing, or the context or inflection, in speech.

So if the context does not make it clear the precise intention, then it would be smarter to use "Bob is fat" as that phrase is quite clear.